# Enter Credentials not responding on QGIS startup?

Tags: qgis

I am running QGIS 2.18.3 
I was recently creating a project that contained WFS layers that required logon details.

Now whenever I try to start QGIS it brings up the following window that cannot be dismissed.

[image]

I have tried editing the registry to remove all the recent projects form the list.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled QGIS
but the problem persists.

Currently my QGIS is completely un-usable.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by using the QGIS browser to delete the WFS connections that were causing the connection problem.